# Extending XFeatureCall scope

Tags: xtext

This has been puzzling me for a while... I have done research, tried lots of things but failed miserably. The time has come to ask here.

My grammar has this rule to define types:

```
MyTypeDeclaration returns XExpression:
    =>({MyTypeDeclaration} type=JvmTypeReference name=ValidID '(')
    (params+=FullJvmFormalParameter (',' params+=FullJvmFormalParameter)*)?
  ')' block=XBlockExpression
;
```

Of course, in the inferrer, I map it to a class (with a supertype MySupertype to differentiate from other Java classes)

```
    members += f.toClass(f.fullyQualifiedName) [
      superTypes += typeRef(MySupertype)
      ...

      members += f.toConstructor [
        for (p : f.params)
          parameters += p.toParameter(p.name, p.parameterType)
        body = f.block
      ]
      ...
    ]
```

What I need is to invoke this class as a function, e.g. using XFeatureCall. XFeatureCall::feature is a JvmIdentifiableElement and so is MyTypeDeclaration when mapped (in the compiler I will add a "new" prefix to call the class constructor). However, naturally, XFeatureClass does not include Java classes in its default scope.

So the question is, how to change this behavior? I need to include MyTypeDeclaration instances (or, more generally, Java classes with MySupertype as superclass) in XFeatureClass scope. I looked at the type computer, getLinkingCandidates and al but it looks too arcane for me.

I use version 2.15 as I need GWT...

Please help as I am really stuck at this point...

Thanks,

Martin

Comment: gwt support is still in 2.17.1. besides that i dont get your question. where is the featurecall you are talking about. or is it about the generation of the constructor? if yes you should have a look at what xtend does for constructors https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-xtend/blob/23f9410dd4be035bfc841c8eec5a9a8876caeab7/org.eclipse.xtend.core/src/org/eclipse/xtend/core/jvmmodel/XtendJvmModelInferrer.java#L721

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for answering! I'm glad to learn GWT support is still active (I will detail my question in the next comment)

Comment: @ChristianDietrich It is not about the generation of the constructor. The XFeatureCall I am talking about is the one in Xbase grammar (and in my grammar too). I am using it to refer to Java methods and data members. I also want to use if for MyTypeDeclaration generated class constructors so its default scope needs now to encompass some JvmConstructor (the ones which superclass is MySupertype) too. Then, if a XFeatureCall element points to a JvmConstructor, the custom type computer will automatically generate a "new <JvmConstructor>(<parms>)" code. Pls tell if further clarification is needed.

Comment: @ChristianDietrich "the custom type computer will automatically generate" should have been "the custom compiler will automatically generate"...

Comment: some pseudo code is vs expected would help

Comment: Thanks @ChristianDietrich, sorry for the confusion. I extended the scope of my question :-) [in a new StackOvervlow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56168010/in-xtext-how-to-tweak-certain-function-calls). Hopefully it will become clearer...